# How to check if array value exists in ionic 3

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, object

I'm new to ionic 3. I'm geting an array which is selected from dropdown **option: {"3":"5","4":"7"}**.

now i need to check the dropdown value with this:

```
"variant_json": "{\"14\":\"5,7\",\"15\":\"5,8\",\"16\":\"6,7\",\"17\":\"6,8\"}"
```

For Example:

In dropdown, if i select **5,7** means it should check from  "variant_json" and need to show its key is **14**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**Object.keys**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [**find**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
let json = JSON.parse("{\"14\":\"5,7\",\"15\":\"5,8\",\"16\":\"6,7\",\"17\":\"6,8\"}")

let findKeyByValue = (value) =>{
  let found = Object.keys(json).find((key)=>json[key] === value)
  return found ? found : 'Not found'
}

console.log(findKeyByValue('5,7'))
console.log(findKeyByValue('5,8'))
console.log(findKeyByValue('9,9'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.entries`:

```js
 

const obj = {
"variant_json": "{\"14\":\"5,7\",\"15\":\"5,8\",\"16\":\"6,7\",\"17\":\"6,8\"}"
};

const [, key ] = Object.entries(obj.variant_json).find(([k, v]) => v == "5,7");

console.log(key);
```